# Downloading file from internet and saving in specific folder using Java

Tags: java

I want to download some files from internet.
I found a promising answer in question [How to download and save a file from Internet using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921262/how-to-download-and-save-a-file-from-internet-using-java/921400#921400) .
How ever I do not know how to save the downloaded files to specific folder say /user/home/Desktop/Download ?

Comment: Pass the file location to `FileOutputStream` in the example you are refering. `FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/user/home/Desktop/Download/file.txt");`

Comment: if you want to specify the folder, just add the folder path in your file name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just give the relative or absolute file path when specifying the file name in the [`FileOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.lang.String%29).

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/user/home/Desktop/Download/myFile.extn");
```

Comment: and don't forget to add escape characters for \ if you are in windows.